# Smarty array in tpl

Tags: php, smarty

In PHP file I have an array when print_r looks like  `array([response_code] => 100, [products[0][price]] => 149.00 [products[0][name]] => 'Blah blah.....')` and it is assigned to by this:

```
$smarty->assign('order_details', $order_details); //$order_details is the array above.
```

Now on template, I can display response_code by:

```
{$order_details.response_code}
```

But how can I display the product name? I tried:

1. `{$order_details.products[0][name]}`
2. `{$order_details.products[0].name}`
3. `{$order_details.products.0.name}`

But nothing worked. Please some one help...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
$smarty->assign('order_details', $order_details); //$order_details is the array above.
```

**Now on template, I can display by fetching array values like this:**

```
{section name=i loop=$order_details}

{$order_details[i].name}

{/section}
```